# Change Firebase auth app name for 1Password

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin, 1password

I'm using Firebase to enable Google/etc. sign-in. Having configured the public-facing name of the app, it looks just fine:

[image: Google Oauth2 screen showing "My App"]

But with 1Password running (in Chrome), after logging on I get a notification showing:

[image: 1Password notification showing "My-app-auth"]

i.e., the internal/Firebase panel project name.

Is this solely a 1Password issue? Presumably I can change this somehow if they're getting access to it? It's something that might be a little confusing or even concerning to an end-user.